# How do I sit properly and why?

Tags: posture

I’m trying to follow the advice from the following video and sit up straight and sit on my sitting bones.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkDNMuG46kk

I feel the muscles on the sides of my lower back (I suppose those are the lats) and the whole position is extremely tiring.

To make matters more worse, I read it's not correct to sit straight, but one should rather be leaned backwards. That seems sketchy to me, since the neck then seems to be in unnatural position.

In summary:

1. should I be sitting on my sitting bones?
2. should I sit up straight or be leaned backwards (neglecting the weird position for my neck)?
3. why are my lats hurting me whe trying to follow the advice from the video?
4. (bonus) is there anything about sitting the science is settled in?
5. why are we advised to stand up every 20 minutes?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about fitness and contains multiple broad questions.

Comment: @JohnP alright. would you care to advise me a stackexchange branch that would be a better fit?